# Making a List Element (ul/li) Mobile Friendly/Responsive in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

We have a "As Seen On" press column on desktop near the footer. On desktop it works properly and the logos are all centered on one line. However, it does the same for mobile and on mobile I need the logos to be stacked instead of all one one line so you don't scroll all the way to the right on your phone or tablet.

I'm not 100% sure but I think I need a media query but I am kinda new to formatting CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class='clearfix'></div>
<div class='center' style = "margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:5%">
    <h2 class="page-header text-center">As Seen On</h2>
    <br>
        <ul class="press">
          <li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="One" src="" /></a>
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">One</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Two" src="" /></a>
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Two</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Three" src="" /></a>
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Three</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Four" src="" /></a>
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Four</span>
          </li><li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.press {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.press > li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for can be easily achieved with a few lines of CSS. You can view the CSS I've created (and documented) in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8oLxr7ke/

```css
.press {
    display: block;  /* Remove bullet points; allow greater control of positioning */
    padding: 0;      /* Override defaults for lists */
    margin: 0;       /* Override defaults for lists */
    width: 100%;     /* Get the row full width */
}

.press li {
    display: inline-block; /* Get all images to show in a row */
    width: 25%;            /* Show 4 logos per row */
    text-align: center;    /* Centre align the images */
}

@media (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 501px) {
    .press li { width: 50%; } /* Show 2 logos per row on medium devices (tablets, phones in landscape) */
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .press li { width: 100%; } /* On small screens, show one logo per row */
}
```

```html
<div class='clearfix'></div>
<div class='center' style = "margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:5%">
    <h2 class="page-header text-center">As Seen On</h2>
        <ul class="press">
          <li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="One" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">One</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Two" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Two</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Three" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Three</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Four" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Four</span>
          </li><li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

In essence, what my code does is:

- Set up a rudimentary grid system
- Show four logos on large screens
- Show two logos on medium screens
- Show only one logo on small screens

---

If you don't want to be restricted to showing a set number of logos, you could do the following:

View on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5m0whf3k/

```css
.press {
  display: table;      /* Required for table-cell to work on li's */
  padding: 0;          /* Override defaults for lists */
  margin: 0;           /* Override defaults for lists */
  width: 100%;         /* Get the row full width */
  text-align: center;  /* Centre align grid items */
}

.press li {
  display: table-cell;   /* Get all images to show in a row */
  text-align: center;    /* Centre align the images */
}

@media (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 501px) {
  .press li { width: 50%; } /* Show 2 logos per row on medium devices (tablets, phones in landscape) */
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .press li { width: 100%; } /* On small screens, show one logo per row */
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .press {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .press li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='clearfix'></div>
<div class='center' style = "margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:5%">
    <h2 class="page-header text-center">As Seen On</h2>
        <ul class="press">
          <li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="One" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">One</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Two" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Two</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Three" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Three</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Four" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Four</span>
          </li><li>
            <div class="press-logo">
              <img alt="Four" src="" />
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Five</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Important note:**

In your HTML code there were closing `</a>` tags after the `<img>` tags but no opening `<a>` tags - *this is invalid code*. In my example I have removed those for you.

Also, you shouldn't need the `<br>` between the `<h2>` and the `<ul class="press">` as the press list will be full width and on its own *row* thanks to the `display: block;`.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the HTML. However, what happens if I added more than 4 logos? I added 5 and it goes to second row

Comment: I've updated my answer with an option if you don't know how many logos will be shown - let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Oh, also, I noticed another little error in the code - there was an additional opening `<li>` just after the last item in the list - I've removed it in my last code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your viewport, if the problem persists, then opt in for media queries

Answer (score -2):

```js
 function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        document.getElementById("header1").classList.toggle("relative");
        document.getElementById("button_icon").classList.toggle("change_icon");
    }
```

```css
.wrap{
    min-height: calc( 100vh - 86px );
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
}

header{
    text-align: center;
}

header div ul{
}

#first_h1{
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#slider{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #34c489;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #34c489, rgba(52, 196, 137, 0.30), rgba(52, 196, 137, 0)), url("../img/england_landscape_2-wallpaper-2880x1620.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.boxing{
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#img_of_slider{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

div header div ul li{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/*==================*/
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 60%;
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;

}

.dropdown-content li{
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.dropdown-content li a{
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(64, 247, 171, 0.36);
}

.show {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 56px;
    background-color: #34c489;
}

.relative{
    position: relative;
}

.change_icon{
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 60%;
    background-color: green;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 680px) {

    #first_h1{
        float: left;
        padding-left: 40px;
        color: #000000;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .dropdown-content li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .dropdown-content li a{
        color: #000000;
    }

    .float{
        float: left;
        width: 28%;
        padding: 2%;
    }

    .clear_fix::after{
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    #img_of_slider{
        width: 250px;
    }

    .dropbtn{
        display: none;
    }

    .dropdown-content{
        display: block;
        float: right;
        padding-right: 50px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-content li:hover{
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normaliz.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css"/>
    <title>Best city guide | Baneh</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <header id="header1">
        <div class="clear_fix boxing">
            <a href="#"><h1 id="first_h1">city</h1></a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" id="button_icon" class="dropbtn"></button>
                <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="news.html">news</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <div id="slider">
            <img id="img_of_slider" src="img/manager.png" alt="city icon"/>
            <h1>Best City Guide</h1>
            <h3>city</h3>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```